# How to execute a cron every 5 minutes at 1 AM to 2 AM

Tags: linux, cron

All,

I want to execute a command in cron from 1 AM to 2 PM every 5 minutes. How can I schedule that

Answer (score 4):

Use the cron expression
1Am to 2 AM

```
*/5 1 * * * command
```

1am to 2pm

```
*/5 1-13 * * * command
```

Comment: will this work :*/5 1-2 * * *  "ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 > logfile.txt"

Comment: Remove quotes   */5 1-2 * * *  ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 > logfile.txt

Comment: I want to create the logfile with same date in one file and next day the cron should create another file with date extension. how can I do that

Comment: will this work */5 1-2 * * *  ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 >> /root/cpustat/logfile_`date +"%d-%m-%Y"`.txt

Comment: The cron is not able to generate the log file when I append date and execute every minute.

Comment: */5 1-2 * * * ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 >> /root/cpustat/logfile_\`date +"%d-%m-%Y"\`.txt

Comment: add \` around date

Comment: can you give complete syntax

Comment: */5 1-2 * * * ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 >> /root/cpustat/logfile_\`date +"%d-%m-%Y"\`.txt

Comment: Can you just check changing the path `/root/cpustat/` to your home direcotory

Comment: yeah it exist the cron works when I dont append date

Comment: * * * * *  ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10 > /root/cpustat/logfile_`date +\%y\%m\%d`.txt
 worked

Comment: Does it really fits author requirements? I think it should be */5 1-13 * * *, otherwise it will be 1 - 14 with the last hour so 14:05, 14:10 etc... That's not what author asked.

Answer (score -1):

you would go like so

```
* *5/ 13-14 * *
```

Comment: The order of your options is incorrect and `*5/` won't work.